# how do i convert text into an image using php's imagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have a text files which I'm trying to convert into images. I know how to do this with GD but I'm having trouble finding suitable functions with imagick/imagemagick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want [annotateImage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-annotateimage.php) there will be more than that you need to do like setFont() ,setTextAlignment() etc...  but that should get you going

Comment: @incognito dis this get you going ?